# Remove single quote when using .join on an array (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following fuction to post to a URL. Part of it requires a year range to be specified. I'm using a .join to put the array of years into the content variable (the post request data).

```py
import requests

def getdata(yearMin, yearMax):
    currentYear = yearMin
    years = []
    while currentYear <= yearMax:
        years.append(str(currentYear))
        currentYear +=1

    content = {"page": 1, "pageCount": 10000, "releaseDate": [", ".join(['"%s"' % y for y in years])],"sort": {"releaseDate": "desc"},"type": "catalog"}

    print(content)

    x = requests.post('https://www.website.com/api/search/terms', json = content)

    return x.text

print(getdata(2008, 2010))
```

The problem I'm having is that it is putting single quotes around the list of years:

```json
{'page': 1, 'pageCount': 10000, 'releaseDate': ['"2008", "2009", "2010"'], 'sort': {'releaseDate': 'desc'}, 'type': 'catalog'}
```

How can I prevent this so that it doesn't add the single quotes?

Comment: If you don't want the elements inside the list to be surrounded by single quotes you should do: ```["%s" % y for y in years]``` instead of ```[", ".join(['"%s"' % y for y in years])]```.

Since ```join``` will fuse all elements to a single string.

Comment: Your content dictionary has a key called `releaseDate`. This key has a value that's a list. The first element of this list is a string. This is indicated by the surrounding apostrophes. The contents of the string are: `"2008", "2009", "2010"`. It seems unnecessary to do this. You could probably simply do `"releaseDate": years` in the line that creates `content`. This sets the value of the `"releaseDate"` key to the list containing the integers `2008`, `2009`, and `2010`.

Comment: wont be this efficient way `content = {"page": 1, "pageCount": 10000, "releaseDate": years, "sort": {"releaseDate": "desc"}, "type": "catalog"}`

Comment: You should do as the above-mentioned since you don't need to format the years.